# Getting specific array data when multiple arrays are printed

Tags: php, arrays

I need to get the specific array data from a print when it is multiple different arrays printed.

This code:

```
$matches = $client->upcoming();

print_r($matches);
```

Prints out this:

```
Array (
[0] => HltvApi\\Entity\\Match Object (
 [details:protected] =>
 [data:protected] => Array (
 [id] => 2338619
 [status] => 1
 [team1] => KINGZZZ
 [team2] => Equinox
 [url] => /matches/2338619/kingzzz-vs-equinox-swiss-esports-league-fall-season-2019-finals
 [type] => 3
 [event] => Swiss Esports League Fall Season 2019 Finals
 [timestamp] => 1576428300
 )
 [client:protected] => HltvApi\\Client Object (
 [proxyList:protected] => Array (
 )
 [baseUrl:protected] => https://hltv.org
 )
)
[1] => HltvApi\\Entity\\Match Object (
 [details:protected] =>
 [data:protected] => Array (
 [id] => 2338432
 [status] => 1
 [team1] => mousesports
 [team2] => OG
 [url] => /matches/2338432/mousesports-vs-og-cs-summit-5
 [type] => 3
 [event] => cs_summit 5
 [timestamp] => 1576429200
 )
 [client:protected] => HltvApi\\Client Object (
 [proxyList:protected] => Array (
 )
 [baseUrl:protected] => https://hltv.org
 )
)
[2] => HltvApi\\Entity\\Match Object (
 [details:protected] =>
 [data:protected] => Array (
 [id] => 2338595
 [status] => 1
 [team1] => ECLOT
 [team2] => EXORS
 [url] => /matches/2338595/eclot-vs-exors-esl-nationals-czsk-season-2
 [type] => 3
 [event] => ESL Nationals CZSK Season 2
 [timestamp] => 1576429200
 )
 [client:protected] => HltvApi\\Client Object (
 [proxyList:protected] => Array (
 )
 [baseUrl:protected] => https://hltv.org
 )
)
```

So I basically only want to fetch the array data from the "first" array **[1]** where [id] = 2338432. 
And yes I know that I could do `$matches = $client->upcoming()[1];` but I need to get to that array by **[id]**.

I have tried something like this to get it working, but it doesn't.

```
$matches = $client->upcoming()["'id'=>'2338619'"];
```

So, how do I get that specific array data by "searching" by the id of the array?

Comment: try wrapping your code around an if statement if that works as per your demands.

Comment: How would that look? I don't think I get it

Comment: `if($client->upcoming()[1]['id'] == '2338619'){ //do as you like }`

Comment: That won't work. Because the dilemma is that I actually don't know that [1] holds id 2338619. I need to get to that array without knowing it is number [1]. Only by id

Comment: Then you'll have to loop through the array to get to your id.

Comment: So there is basically no other way?

Comment: I guess that's the only way forward.

Answer (score 0):

Using …

```php
$matching = array_filter(
    $matches,
    function(array $subArray) {
        return '2338619' === $subArray;
    }
)[0];
```

… you will get only the array which has the ID you are looking for. If you don’t know if there is a match, you should not use `[0]` directly, but rather check whether `$matching` contains anything at all.

Comment: BlueM need your help in symfony